# Files needed to handle SSL Certificate of Server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I have a VM. I generated SSL Certificates:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365
```

After that wrote a web server using Flask with argument ssl_context:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Flask is running!"


@app.route("/data")
def some_func():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context=("cert.pem", "key.pem"))
```

Now I have another VM in the same network, where I have a client app that requests some data:

```
import requests
import json

SERVER_URL = 'https://example.com/data'

token = "some_token"

def _send():
    query = """some_query"""

    data = {'query': query}

    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
               'Authorization': "Bearer %s" % token
               }

    response = requests.post(SERVER_URL,
                             data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'),
                             headers=headers,
                             verify=Flase)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        res = json.loads(response.text)
        return True, res, None
    return False, None, response.text


print(_send())
```

What I need now is to pass to `verify` argument path to the some certs that will help me to check SSL Certificates of Server. But which files I need to pass to verify? Same `cert.pem` and `key.pem` that I generated and passed to Flask app as `ssl_contextor` or I need to generated another file (If yes, how can I generate/create that file)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've slightly modified your example:

1. generate certificate with `CommonName` and `SubjectAltName` (in this example I've used `domain.test`):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -out cert.pem -keyout key.pem -days 365 -subj /CN=domain.test -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:domain.test"
```

2. the code for running the server part:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Flask is running!"


@app.route("/data", methods=["GET", "POST"])  # <-- add methods= here
def some_func():
    return jsonify({"result": "Hello World!"})  # <-- return some example data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, ssl_context=("cert.pem", "key.pem"))
```

3. the client part:

```py
import requests
import json

SERVER_URL = "https://domain.test:5000/data"  # <-- put domain.test here

token = "some_token"


def _send():
    query = """some_query"""

    data = {"query": query}

    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Bearer %s" % token,
    }

    response = requests.post(
        SERVER_URL,
        data=json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"),
        headers=headers,
        verify="cert.pem",  # <-- put cert.pem here
    )

    if response.status_code == 200:
        res = json.loads(response.text)
        return True, res, None

    return False, None, response.text


print(_send())
```

---

Output without any warnings:

```py
(True, {'result': 'Hello World!'}, None)
```

Comment: so I need to take cert.pem file yes???

Comment: @Samvel yes, only cert.pem is needed on client.